# counting the amount of elements in a nested list using a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

i have this program that reads data from a file and then turns it into a nested list and im trying to count the amount of elements in it using a dictionary if possible and output something like this
I have L which is a list and the program should check if the elements are in that list and if so count them. which i haven't been able to figure out how to do

```
def count(fnm,L):
    try:
        fp = open(fnm,'r')
        count ={}
        table = []
        l_temp = []
        for line in fp:
            line = line.strip()
            l_temp.append(line)
        fp.close()
        i = 0
        while i < len(l_temp):
            last = l_temp[i].split(' ')
            table.append(last)
            i += 1
        return table
    except IOError:
        print("Error! no such file")

def main():
    L = ['CSE', '1310', '1104', '1105']
    fnm = 'task2_test1.txt'
    q = count(fnm,L)
    print(q)
main()
```

output:

```
[['5333', '1105'], ['CSE', '1310', 'CSE', '1104'], ['CSE', '2325']]

3 : CSE 1310 CSE 1104
1 : 5333 1105
1 : CSE 2325
```

Comment: what exactly you want ??

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, in order to get answer, please read and follow this [guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that, show what the expected input, output are.

Comment: You aren't using `L` inside of your `count` function.